# Sikuli - How to turn off FindFailed exceptions, setThrowException() not working

Tags: python, exception, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I'm using Sikulix IDE v2.0.5 and trying to search on the screen a specific word, then look at his right if there is another specific word.

I saw that I should use `setThrowException(False)` to Skip the FindFailed Exception, but when implementing it I still get them thrown.

[image]

[image]

```
[error] FindFailed ( 1642158588596.png: (74x10) seen at (443, 190) with 1,00 in R[517,190 300x10]@S(0) )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first
line: module ( function ) statement 
6: main (  <module> )     if link.right(300).find("1642158588596.png"):
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `SCREEN.setThrowException(False)` wasn't taken into account after using Region's `right()` function.

For it to work I needed to set the exception on the new Region returned by `right()`:

```
for word in words:
    word = word.right(300)
    word.setThrowException(False)
...
```